# fatal: could not unset 'branch.master.remote'

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to remove git remote. I have just removed heroku remote url with the command

```
$ git remote rm heroku
```

but when I try to use this on remote for bitbucket(origin). It fails with an error

```
git remote rm origin        
fatal: could not unset 'branch.master.remote'
```

where's when listing remote with

```
$ git remote -v
```

clearly mentions

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org:username/myapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:username/myapp.git (push)
```

**.git/config**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
[branch "static-pages"]
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:myUserName/mY_Hidden_App.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Do you have the permissions on Bitbucket to do this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure? How do I check that?

Comment: last time I removed remote url linked to Github with same command & worked just fine. Is there something different with bitbucket? 

now that I cloned this repo on my local machine for some tweaking. I don't wish to set remote links. In case I do something wrong or mess something. I wish to keep it local just for play purpose

Comment: Could edit your question to include the contents of the section `[branch "master"]` in the `.git/config` file of your repository?

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is entire conf file

Comment: Have you tried the `git remote rm` command only once, or several times? I could reproduce a similar issue in a dummy repository, but found that the command worked after it failed once.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have used once more. I had this repository hosted on public Github account. I then pointed it to Bitbucket private account. I have used "git remote rm heroku" so I have used it twice

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough - I meant: have you tried `git remote rm origin` again after it failed once? Try it again - if it still doesn't work delete the `[branch "master"]` line in the config file and try it again.

Comment: @mkrieger1 done still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132791/discussion-between-mkrieger1-and-abhimanyu-aryan).

Comment: Blindly copying your config file into a git repo and running ``git remote rm origin`` works fine for me. I am running git version 1.8.3.1. As a wild guess, I would let master track another remote and then try again to delete origin.

Answer (score 2):

This error message (`fatal: could not unset` ) should not appear anymore with Git 2.12.2 or more (March 2017)

See [commit 20690b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20690b213975ad3e9b1bc851f434d818bd2d1de9) (18 Feb 2017) by [Ross Lagerwall (`rosslagerwall`)](https://github.com/rosslagerwall).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3e5c639](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e5c63943d35be1804d302c0393affc4916c3dc3), 27 Feb 2017)</sup>

"`git remote rm X`", when a branch has remote `X` configured as the value of its `branch.*.remote`, tried to remove `branch.*.remote` and `branch.*.merge` and failed if either is unset.

Make sure the `[branch "master"]` line is gone from your local config, and again, with the latest Git 2.12.2 released yesterday, this won't happen again.

Comment: upgrade to latest version helped me